# How to make disappeared status bar on Linux appear?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, vnc

I am using VNC viewer to remotely access a Linux machine. The problem is when I accessed it, I pressed a button which caused the status bar to disappear (containing menus such as 'Application', etc).

Then I couldn't get it again, even the title bar of Eclipse disappeared and I couldn't find any way to restore it. Even terminal is not getting opened. Please give me few suggestions.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. I don't really see the question from the title in the body itself.

Answer (score 1):

how about Alt-F4

also try to keep Alt pressed and while inside the App's window drag it in different directions, maybe menus/status bar/title bar are outside of VNC window

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your window manager just exited. What window manager do you have? Perhaps you entered a hotkey that is setup to make your window manager quit, or you presses a button for the same. In such situations, you should be able to just run the window manager's exe and your window decorations and menu should come back.